# Rowcounts of all tables in a database in Netezza

Tags: sql, netezza

I am migrating data from MS SQL to **Netezza** and so I need to find the **row counts** of all tables in a database (in Netezza). Any **query** for the same would be of an immense help to me as I'm completely new to this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Some SQL client tools can do that for you. Which tool are you using?

Comment: Can you use stored procedures, If yes than the problem is easy. Just iterate over desired table names from _v_table table and get row_count from that.

I can provide you complete working code if required with help of Stored procedures.

Answer (score 5):

This query does it directly from _v_table:

```
SELECT TABLENAME, RELTUPLES FROM _V_TABLE where objtype = 'TABLE' ORDER BY RELTUPLES
```

Answer (score 2):

something like this should work:

```
select 'select '||chr(39)||tablename||chr(39)||' as entity, count(1) from '||tablename||' union all' 
from _v_table 
where object_type ='TABLE';
```

copy/paste the result, remove the last "union all".

Comment: should be objtype instead object_type

Answer (score 0):

I have never used Netezza but googled and found:

http://www.folkstalk.com/2009/12/netezza-count-analytic-functions.html

```
SELECT dept_id,
       salary,
       COUNT(1) OVER() total_cnt
FROM Employees
```

If you don't know what tables that exists:

http://www.folkstalk.com/2009/11/netezza-system-catalog-views.html

```
select * from _v_table;
```

Comment: That returns only the rowcount for a single table, not for all tables in the database.

Comment: Correct, you will have to loop over the tables to get the count for each individual table. I'm not sure whether the OP wants the sum of counts for all tables or the individual count for all tables.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to acquire the row counts for a table (if you have access to the operating system level) is to use the Netezza nz_get_table_rowcount command. You can enter, "nz_get_table_rowcount -h" to get all of the help text on this command, but the format is:

Usage:    nz_get_table_rowcount  [database]

Purpose:  Perform a "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ;" to get its true rowcount.
          Thus, this script results in a full table scan being performed.

Inputs:   The database name is optional.  If not specified, then $NZ_DATABASE 
          will be used instead.

```
      The table name is required.  If only one argument is specified, it 
      will be taken as the table name.

      If two arguments are specified, the first will be taken as the 
      database name and the second will be taken as the table name.
```

Outputs:  The table rowcount is returned.

Use this command in a shell script to cycle through all of the tables within a database. Use nz_get_table_names to get the list of tables within a database.